# What is the best algorithm for sorting biggest X number in a set

Tags: algorithm, sorting

What is the best algorithm for extracting the sorted list of the X largest numbers from a set of N numbers (N > X). With most algorithms we can do that in `O(NlogN)` time. But is it possible to do better than that? For example with a Binary Tree: `O(NLogX)`?. The numbers in the set are completely random.

Comment: depends upon what you mean with "biggest X number". And sorting and one distinct number seem a bit contrary. Please clarify what you actually ask for.

Comment: For example we have a this number set : `3 5 2 7 1` and we want biggest 3(which is X at question) number so we  should print `7 5 3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [min heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) of size X.

Insert the first *X* elements into the heap. Starting at element *X*+1 (call it *e*), compare it to the top of the heap *m* (the minimum so far). Note that this comparison will be done in constant time. If *e* > *m*, then *e* deserves to get in (extract *m* and insert *e*). Do that for each element of the set. At the end of this process, your heap contains the *X* largest numbers. Then *extract-min* *X* times will give you the sorted list you expect.

Each of the *N* iterations performs a potential `O(lgX)` extract/insert operation, so the first step is `O(NlgX)` time. Then the cost of *X* *extract-min* in your min heap will simply be `O(XlgX)`, which gives us an overall complexity of `O(NlgX)`.

Comment: What is the difference between using `binary tree` and `min heap`?

Comment: @Pareidolia: A min heap is going to be somewhat faster. In particular, you can find the largest item in O(1). In a binary heap, finding the largest (or smallest) item is O(log n). In addition, unless you use a balanced binary tree (an AVL tree, for example), you run the risk of ending up with a degenerate tree and all of your operations become O(x) rather than O(log x).

Answer (score 2):

The "best" algorithm depends on many things, including the size of the data set, whether you can modify the original list, and how many items you want to select.

For example, if you have 10 items and you're looking for the largest three, it's trivial to just sort the list and pick the last three. It might be faster to call [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) to re-order the array so that the three largest are at the front, and then sort those three. But the small amount of time you'd save is unlikely to be worth the added complexity.

If you want to pick the top 1000 from 10,000, though, then you definitely want to use Quickselect. Quickselect is O(n), whereas Quicksort is O(n log n). But both Quicksort and Quickselect modify the original list.

If you can't modify the original list, or you can't hold the entire list in memory, then the heap selection algorithm mentioned in a previous answer is the best way to go.

Also, even though the Quickselect is O(n) and the heap selection algorithm is O(n log x), the heap selection algorithm can still be faster than Quickselect when you're selecting a very small percentage of the items. For example, if you want the top 100 out of 1,000,000, the heap selection algorithm will be faster. I did a fairly detailed writeup about this in my blog a while back. See [When theory meets practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/).

Answer (score 0):

If X is small, then insertion sort is probably the way to go.

Think of the "top 10 scores" list on a video game. After you play the game, what happens to the list? Unless your score is higher than the score in 10th place, nothing happens: your score is too low to make the list. If, however, your score is high enough to make the list, then insertion sort will put it in its proper place in the list, moving all lower scores out of the way to make room for it. In this latter case, the old 10th-place score becomes the new 11th-place score and falls off the list.